# Python : Operator Overloading a specific type

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I'd like to be able to have the operator of my class interact with regular types in a way that I define. Lets say, for example, I have:

```
class Mynum(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
   self.x = x
  def __add__(self, other):
   return self.x + other.x

a = Mynum(1)
b = Mynum(2)

print a+b
```

This works just fine, but now if I try to do:

```
print a+2
```

I get an error since an `int` does not have a member named `x`. How do I define `Mynum` + `int` in the class? This sounds like a job for decorators or metaclasses, but I'm terribly unfamiliar with their usage. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694619/dynamic-operator-overloading-on-dict-classes-in-python) seems similar, but not quite identical.

Comment: check the type or `other` or presence of `x` attribute.

Comment: don't forget to do:
`__radd__` = `__add__`
also (even though it doesn't fix your problem)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return self.x + other.x
    elif isinstance(other, int):
        return self.x + other
    else:
        raise TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: '{}' and '{}'").format(self.__class__, type(other))
```

Comment: Thank you, I've never seen `isinstance` before. Is this considered the correct way to do this, or should I use the try/except block proposed by unutbu?

Comment: The `try… except` clause is fast when no exception is raised, and slow otherwise.  Therefore, you can use it if adding two instances of your class is the most common use of the overloaded addition.  Otherwise, the `insinstance` approach is good.

Comment: Shouldn't you return `NotImplemented` instead of raising and exception yourself?

Answer (score 5):

```
class Mynum(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.x + other.x
        except AttributeError:
            return self.x + other
    __radd__=__add__

a = Mynum(1)
b = Mynum(2)

print(a+b)
# 3
print(a+2)
# 3
print(2+a)
# 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use the extra switching and/or exception handling? Using the following would be a simpler approach:

```
class MyNum(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __add__(self, other):
        return other + self.x
    __radd__ = __add__
x = MyNum(5)
y = MyNum(6)
print x + 2
7
print 2 + x
7
print x + y
11
print y + x
11
```