# How do operators handle different types in python

Tags: python

For example, the `+` operator can deal with different types, like int and string. What is the difference between `1+2` and `'a'+'b'`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188666/python-operator-overloading-a-specific-type

Comment: Each of them implements its own [`__add__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, in Python everything is an object. Here, you have two separate expressions: one with two integers and one with two strings. Those are two separate classes which define the `__add__()` method, which will handle (or not) different types.

```
>>> (1).__add__('a')
NotImplemented
>>> (1).__add__(1)
2
>>> 'b'.__add__('a')
'ba'
```

Edit: After a bit of tinkering, it seems that the **add** method of the integer object actually doesn't get called in this instance. The TypeError raised when executing the `1 + 'a'` statement appears to simply be the result of, literally, `1 + 'a'`, whereas calling `(1).add__('a')` returns NotImplemented.

Answer (score 1):

The + operator just uses the `__add__` method from the class of the objects you're dealing with. E.g. if you want to have objects that are points in a 2d plane represented by two floats then it would make sense that addition of them means getting a new point with added coordinates like this

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
   
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)

p = Point(1,1)+Point(2,1)
p.x,p.y
--> (3,2)
```